# Springboot native query not giving result

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

My query works in sql developer but not working using the nativeQuery method .

I have 3 tables

table1: app_id,type,reels

table1: app_id,decision,quality

Note : Due to large class ..only showing the related code and colums

```
@Entity
public class Table1 {

  @Column(name = "app_id")
  private String applicationId;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumn(name = "app_status_id", referencedColumnName = "app_id")
  private table2 table2;

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "app_status")
public class Table2{
  @Column(name = "app_id")
  private String app_id;
}




@Repository
public interface Repository extends JpaRepository<Table1, Long> {

  @Query(value = "select * from Table1 t1 JOIN Table2 t2 on t1.app_id = t2.app_id and t1.app_id=':val'", nativeQuery = true)
List<Object> findResults(@Param("val") String val);

}
```

This works perfect in sqldeveloper but I get this exception from code

```
no-dialect-mapping-for-jdbc-type-101
```

Can someone help me?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: can this https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-no-dialect-mapping-for-jdbc-type/ help you?

Comment: Have you in the application.properties defined spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect or the dialect are you using?

Comment: Hi, thank you for replying but this didn't help me.  This query gives desired result in oracle but through code i am getting this exception